# Is there a way to not use an include statement in every file?

Tags: php, hook

I want to have my site try and verify the user each time they run any page, without having to add the include to every file. Any way to do this?

Comment: @SethBattin How would I get the code to execute on every page though?

Comment: I guess you could use ExplosionPills's answer.  Care to elaborate on why you don't like using include?  If you want to perform an action on every page, then you should run code on every page.  An alternative is only an aesthetic thing.  Like @AlvinWong said.

Comment: Or instead of having many separate php files, where each page depends on the same includes, have a front controller that loads your files.

Comment: I don't want to worry about forgetting the code, and I was also thinking about making an Anti-Dos script, but it would be impractical to edit every file.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I always call that file the router .. have I been using the wrong terminology all this time?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I like to call mine the super controller.  Saying it that way allows me to call my parent model class my super model... :-)

Comment: Add the include file on every page!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `auto_prepend_file`, an ini setting.  This includes a file automatically.  Be careful about what you put in that file, though.

Comment: A server setting seems like a heavy-handed answer to avoid using a simple language feature.

Comment: @SethBattin I don't see how it's heavy-handed .. the prepended file could do a lot of things.

Comment: that's exactly my point.  It could do anything, and anyone reading the code would never know because the code doesn't mention it.  Your code then begins to depend on the operating environment rather than the code itself.  That's a huge hack.  And just to save inserting an include in a few files?

Comment: Its not a good idea to be honest. Suppose a bug appeared and you forgot about appended files (bug was may be there). How anyone will know? There are simple ways out there which does the purpose. Why go on the direction of what is unmanagable?

Comment: It's not the worst solution.  I feel using something similar to a .htaccess rewrite to a central file is a little bit more obvious as opposed to using a setting within php.ini, as this is one of those things where you end up with a hard to track and propagate feature, like dealing with magic quotes and such.

Comment: What are you guys proposing this include file do??  It should be very limited, perhaps setting the error handler and some default includes.  I prefer the idea of having a single file to route all requests through, but I assume this user is not in a position to do that readily.

Answer (score 1):

use switch whit case in your index.php:

```
switch (isset($_GET["page"])?$_GET["page"]:""){

        case 'user': 
                include 'user.php';
        break; 

        default:                
        case '':  
        case 'index': 
                include 'main.php';
        break;
}
```

And call your page: `http://your-website.com/index.php?page=user`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an auto loader in your index or bootstrap file such as:

```
// Autoload any files that are required
function autoLoad($classToLoad)
{
    if(file_exists('file/path/' . $classToLoad . '.php'))
    {
    require('file/path/' . $classToLoad . '.php');
    }
    else if(file_exists('other/file/path/' . $classToLoad . '.php'))
    {
        require('other/file/path/' . $classToLoad . '.php');
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('autoLoad');
```

You can find some more info about auto loading in the
[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).